# wrong use case for getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, xml

Im trying to get the temperature value from an xml file:

```
XML: <temperature value="280.15" min="278.15" max="281.15" unit="kelvin"/>
JS: getElementsByTagName("temperature");
```

The above does not work(shows nothing).

```
XML: <country>GB</country>
JS: getElementsByTagName("country")
```

The above does work(shows GB).

I would appreciate if someone could explain why the first example doesnt work and how I can make it work.

Comment: Your first works just fine for me (though of course for both you need to call `getElementsByTagName` on `document`) https://jsfiddle.net/92tpLdb8/

Comment: How are you parsing the XML? `DOMParser`?

Comment: @Ry- I'm parsing using responseXML

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that XML tags cannot be self-closing. To make your first example work, just do this:

```
<temperature value="280.15" min="278.15" max="281.15" unit="kelvin"></temperature>
```

Also make sure you're using `document.getElementsByTagName()` not just `getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: The api only provides it as self closing, is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: XML tags can’t be self-closing…? Since when?